# split an array into 2 objects laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

i have an array which is like below :

```
"["events/81.jpg","events/Ancient.2.jpg","events/post.jpg"]"
```

this is the result of a dd now what i want to do is to change this to a collection with 3 objects so i can loop into that and show it in front end . how can i do that what i tried was like below :

```
explode(',','$media');
```

but this brings the `[` charachter too so i cant show it in front end . the full result of the dd is as below :

```
attributes: array:11 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "test"
    "description" => "<p>test</p>"
    "teaser" => "events\December2020\G0SiKVIYomU9SMuuE8ux.jpg"
    "media" => "["events/88c7ae4a-8a0a-467f-b09c-0f50206a35eb.jpg","events/Ancient.Aliens.S14E05.480p.Film2Movie_WS.mkv_snapshot_06.45.jpg","events/post.jpg"]"
    "price" => 11998
    "start_at" => "2020-12-28 00:00:00"
    "finish_at" => "2020-12-28 00:00:00"
    "is_free" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-12-28 11:15:00"
    "updated_at" => "2020-12-28 11:30:41"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an array, it's a string representation of one. You can [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) it:

```
json_decode($media)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => events/81.jpg
    [1] => events/Ancient.2.jpg
    [2] => events/post.jpg
)
```

Comment: ok cool i see it now thanks can i convert it object from string or i should do it after changing to array

Comment: @Farshad you can convert it into a collection after it's been converted to an array. e.g. `$collection = collect(json_decode($media));`